# How to pass < in xml?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2" 
   android:text="< 4 minutes" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If i pass "< 4 minutes" in the text xml gives error.

Can any way to achieve this thing in xml ?

please suggest

Comment: You need to escape certain characters, just like any other XML file. Try `&lt;` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"<" is a special character in HTML and xml.

To use it replace "<" with & # 6 0;.

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2" 
   android:text="&#60; 4 minutes" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is a helpfull link, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2" 
   android:text="&lt; 4 minutes" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```